# limit of $\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(\frac{1}{2})^x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to compute the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x},$$
for which we have the indetermination $\frac{+\infty}{0}$.

I know that the final answer is $+\infty$.
However, I am not sure if the way I am solving it is correct
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty} 2^xx^{\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty} 2^x . \lim_{x\to +\infty} x^{\frac{1}{2}} = +\infty.+\infty=+\infty,$$
because I know there are some issues when computing $\lim_{x\to \infty} 1^x$, therefore I do not know if doing $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty} 2^xx^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is correct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The conversion in your last line is correct, because for all $x > 0$, $\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x}$ and $ 2^x~x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are equal, so their limits are equal.

Comment: $\frac{+\infty}{0^+}$ is not an indeterminate form -- and there are no issue when computing the limit of $2^x$ when $x\to+\infty$. Two non problems, thus.

Comment: Your work (your way of determining the limit), and your last sentence (above your kind "thankyou"): the answer is yes!

Comment: @amWhy Ok, but then, following the answers, is that not simpler to compute the limit by $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x}=\frac{+\infty}{0}=+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\infty}{0}$  is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that! Can we always say that $\frac{+\infty}{0}=+\infty$?

Comment: No, it could be $-\infty$, if you're approaching $0$ from below, or undefined, if you're alternating across $0$.

Comment: In short: it's not as easy as this answer might suggest to the uninitiated (as indicated by your followup question). You might want to look at $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$, which appears to have the form $\frac{\infty}{0}$, but which actually does not approach a limit. What's true is that *if* the limit exists, it's either $\pm \infty$, but to prove that requires a kind of inverse application of the limit-of-products theorem, which first has to be rigorously extended to include infinite limits.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's correct.  $\left (\frac{1}{2} \right )^{x} = \frac{1}{2^{x}}$, and for each $x$, we have $$\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2^{x}}} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}2^{x}$$

and since these are the same for each $x$, they have the same limit, i.e.,

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2^{x}}} = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty}  x^{\frac{1}{2}}2^{x}.$$

It's kind of like saying: if $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x$ (i.e., $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same function) then $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)$.  It's obvious that this is true if $f(x)$ is the same function as $g(x)$.